# How is the performance after enabling php_pdo_mysql.dll?

Tags: php

Will I notice any loss in performance if I enable php_pdo_mysql.dll in php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enabling an extension will not change much to the way PHP works :

- there will be one more file loaded when PHP starts (negligible, considering the amount of files your application is made of -- and a file loaded often will be kept in RAM by the OS)
- there will be a couple of C function executed when a request starts and stops ; but those generally don't do much (especially, because hurting performances is not the goal)
- considering you probably have database queries and stuff like that, the performance "degradation" introduced by loading one more extension will be **negligible**

So, no, you will not notice anything ; ne need to worry :-)

What really matters, actually, is what that new extension can bring you ; if it can bring you anything good *(and PDO generally can ;-) )*, then, don't hesitate even one second !

*(Well, maybe if you were serving hundreds millions of requests each day, using hundreds of servers, you might notice a small difference -- but that's probably not your case ;-) )*

Answer (score 0):

Will **you** notice? No, relax.